# Can one create a tracking branch with git-branch rather than git-checkout?

Tags: git, git-branch

Suppose that a remote repo `remote` has a branch `spanking_new_branch` that's not represented/referenced in any way in the local repository.  I want to create a local branch that tracks `remote/spanking_new_branch`.

When I search online for ways to do this I only find ones that are based on `git checkout`.  Is there a way to do it using `git branch` only, without using `git checkout`?

(The motivation for this question is only to understand `git` better.)

Comment: Do you want to exclude everything outside that sparkling_new branch?  Otherwise, `fetch` would do, imho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=remote/spanking_new_branch local_branchname
```

where `local_branchname` must exist already. It can be created using `git branch local_branchname <start-point>` (`<start-point>` is commit-ish and can be omitted to use the current commit as start point).

This assumes that the local repository knows about the remote branch, e.g. by a call to `git fetch`.

Comment: `-u <upstream>` or `--set-upstream-to=<upstream>` are the latest variations on this, introduced in git 1.8.

Comment: @torek Thanks for the hint! I edited my answer, because what I wrote there would not work. It was a mix between the old and new version.

Answer (score 0):

Besides [Jonas Wielicki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20453453/1256452), you can do this with `git config` as well.

A local branch *`B`* tracks some other branch when:

- `branch.B.remote` is set, and
- `branch.B.merge` is set.

The branch that is tracked depends on both values.  Normally the first is set to the name of a remote, typically `origin`, and more often than not the `merge` name matches the local name, so that local branch `master` tracks `origin/master` (for instance) because `branch.master.remote` = `origin` and `branch.master.merge` = `master`.

However, the "remote" name can be `.`, in which case the branch actually tracks another local branch!  (This is only useful if the other branch name differs—if the branch "tracks itself", then each update to the branch also updates the branch's upstream, so that the branch is always current, which is pretty silly. :-) )

As a last quirk, the documentation says that the tracking is massaged through the `fetch` line(s) associated with the remote.  I have not tried this myself, but this implies that, e.g.:

```
git config remote.zork.url = ssh://...
git config remote.zork.fetch = '+refs/heads/master:refs/xyzzy/plugh'
git fetch zork
git config branch.master.remote zork
git config branch.master.merge plugh
```

would cause local branch `master` to track `zork`'s `master` even though there would be no "remote branches" for remote `zork` since "remote branches" live in the `refs/remotes/` name-space, and `refs/xyzzy/plugh` is different (and does not even contain the name `master`)!

(I have no idea why it's this complicated.)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is:

```
git branch --track LOCAL_BRANCH_NAME REMOTE/REMOTE_BRANCH_NAME
```

For example:

```
git branch --track spanking_new_branch origin/spanking_new_branch
```

Often, if you use the same name as the remote branch, you can use:

```
git branch --track spanking_new_branch
```

And it will automatically set up to track the remote version.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the format is:

```
git branch --set-upstream ${local_branch} ${remote}/${remote_branch}
```

Example use (assumes topic1 and origin/topic1 already exist):

```
git branch --set-upstream topic1 origin/topic1
```